# photo slide show for arbitrarily many photos using html5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm starting to build my new (photo) homepage from ground up in order to have better control and hopefully make it easier for me to update it. 
One of the things that would help me update the homepage easily is if the homepage could index the photographs that should be showed itself instead of me indexing the pictures and adding a new picture in the code, The code could have an own vector that is updated as soon as the folder is updated with a new picture. If i was to have a slideshow which changes on click I now have this code:

```html
<section id="main_section">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="960"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var imageObj = new Image();

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'landscape1.jpg';
  canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {imageObj.src = 'landscape2.jpg'; }, false);
</script>
```

My hope would be to change the last function so that on every click it changes to the next picture in the vector. i.e.

```js
canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {x=x+1; imageObj.src = vector(x); }, false);
```

where the vector holds the name of the picture files.
Suppose that I have y number of pictures starting with "landscape" in the same folder as the html-file, how do I create this vector?
I hope the question was clear

Answer (score 0):

i thinks this code can help:

1. use Array

> ```
> <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="960"></canvas>
>     <script>
>       var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
>       var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
>       var imageObj = new Image();
>       var vector = new Array('landscape1.jpg','landspcape2.jpg','landscape3.jpg');//to y
>       var x=1;
>       imageObj.onload = function() {
>            context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
>             context.fillRect(0,0,1280,960);
>            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
>       };
>       imageObj.src = vector[0];
>       canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {
>      if(++x>vector.length)x=1;
>      imageObj.src = vector[x]; }, false);
>     </script>
> ```

2 Or just use name not Array

```
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1280" height="960"></canvas>
      <script>
                      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                      var imageObj = new Image();
                      var x=1;

                      imageObj.onload = function() {
                           context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                            context.fillRect(0,0,1280,960);
                           context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
                      };
                      imageObj.src = 'landscape1.jpg'
                      canvas.addEventListener('click', function() {
                     imageObj.src = 'landscape' + (++x) + '.jpg' }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you!Of course that should work! Now I only need to find a way to start over when there is no picture left :)

Comment: if(++x>vector.length)x=1; if there is no picture left, it will change to first picture